# Create List in TCL of objects

Tags: class, oop, tcl

I am new to TCL and I am working on a projects in which i need to create a list of objects from a different list which holds address which I use to access some data.the class which I wrote contains this data.only problem I encounter so far is how to create a list of objects

```
for {set i 0} {$i<$len} {incr i} {
    set dat [lindex $PTR_ARR $i]
    if { $dat != 0x0000000000000000 } {
        set name "Slot Context$i"
        Slot_Context $name $dat 
        append $obj_arr $ptr
    }   
}
```

PTR_ARR- is a list of pointers which will be delivered to class
this implementation is not working and I get errors,I tried to search for info but there is almost no information about implementation of classes in TCL.
Do you have any ideas about what can I do?

Comment: "I get errors". What are the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `obj_arr` is the name of a variable that contains the array you are trying to append to, the proper way to append to it is to a) use the variable *name* rather than the *value* in the append statement, and b) use `lappend` (list append) rather than `append` (string append):

```
lappend obj_arr $ptr
```

If you want to append the actual object rather than `$ptr`, do it like this:

```
lappend obj_arr [Slot_Context $name $dat]
```

The above calls the `Slot_Context` command, then appends the result of that command to the list named `obj_arr`.